# Sending data though PHP post form that isn't provided by the user

Tags: php

I need to pass a variable though $_POST. This varaible will never be supplied by the user interacting with the form. Basically when you click a button it grabs a number from a database, I need to transfer this number from one page, to a form, and from that form to another page. Without the user seeing it or being able to edit it. Later I need to be able to create an array with multiple numbers, right now I'm starting small with just the one. I'm sure it's simple. I figured a cookie would work but when I start have to transfer multiple numbers and then access them, I believe I would run into problems. Unless you can store an array within a cookie.

Perhaps imploding the the array of multiple numbers, say

```
$MyArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$ArrayToString = implode(",",$MyArray);
setcookie("My_Numbers", $ArrayToString, TIMEHERE);
```

and then when I access them just do

```
$NewArray = explode(","$_COOKIE['My_Numbers']);
setcookie("My_Numbers", "", PASTTIME);
print_r($NewArray);
```

I just thought of this while I was writing this up. Hopefully there is a more secure, perhaps easier way.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input name="yourName" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $yourVariable; ?>" />`

if you want to stay away from session variables go this route. otherwise $_SESSION is a decent way to go as well. although i'm not sure what the data is exactly and if it truly belongs in a $_SESSION var

EDIT:

using a hypothetical `person` table

```
//form page user sees
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `personId` = '$_GET['personId']`";

//assume we get the data into $row array
?>

<form action="process.php">
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['personId']; ?>" />

    <input name="firstName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['firstName']; ?>" />

    <input name="lastName" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['lastName']; ?>" />

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

//process.php
<?php
$query = "UPDATE `person` SET `firstName` = '$_POST['firstName']', `lastName` = '$_POST['lastName']' WHERE `personId` = '$_POST['personId']";
?>
```

remember this example is VERY vulnerable to SQL injection. please fetch your data a better way.

Comment: The PHP form is editing a row in my MySQL database, it's similar to PHPMyAdmin's format of editing rows in tables, except you're only editing the data stored in certain columns, not the data type or anything. When click the edit button it brings you to a form, it stores the ID column of the row and the number in it. It uses that number when you get to the form to grab the current information and you can edit it for there. That's easy with just editing one row, because I can just use $_GET.....

Comment: After that though, I need to get it from the form to the page where it saves the information. It uses the ID number to know which SQL row to update. When using multiple ID's I can send them to the editing form through POST ( select with checkboxes from one page and then just throw a bunch of them on one page to edit. After that I need to get the array of ID's from the forms to the page that updates the rows. I can figure out how to do it with both of themse methods and will try them both. Which would you recommend?

Comment: i would recommend the hidden input. $_SESSION data is meant more for data that needs to persist during a users time on your site. more so for things like secure logins and such. if i'm reading it right, the above example should be very close to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use a $_SESSION variable, it will stay active through all pages you're in. Until you destroy them

Comment: Can you store an array in this session?

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at this.